# correlation coefficient equation not working

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, math, vb6

I wrote a VB code for calculating correlation coefficient between original and encrypted image. The correlation coefficient values ranges between 0 to 1, however, after implementing the code below the values are larger then one such as 2 or 4. The equation I worked with is as below:
Can you check why I'm getting these vales, please.

[image]

This is the code I used, please note all variable are set to zero prior to x and y loop:

```
For y = 0 To hgt-1: For x = 0 To wid-1
meanr_o = meanr_o + Red(x, y)
meang_o = meang_o + Grn(x, y)
meanb_o = meanb_o + Blu(x, y)

meanr_e = meanr_e + nred(x, y)
meang_e = meang_e + nGrn(x, y)
meanb_e = meanb_e + nBlu(x, y)

N = N + 1
Next x: Next y

meanr_o = meanr_o / N
meang_o = meang_o / N
meanb_o = meanb_o / N
meanr_e = meanr_e / N
meang_e = meang_e / N
meanb_e = meanb_e / N

 For y = 0 To hgt-1: For x = 0 To wid-1

sumr1 = sumr1 + ((Red(x, y) - meanr_o) * (nred(x, y) - meanr_e))
sumr2 = sumr2 + ((Red(x, y) - meanr_o) ^ 2)
sumr3 = sumr3 + ((nred(x, y) - meanr_e) ^ 2)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
sumg1 = sumg1 + ((Grn(x, y) - meang_o) * (nGrn(x, y) - meang_e))
sumg2 = sumg2 + ((Grn(x, y) - meang_o) ^ 2)
sumg3 = sumg3 + ((nGrn(x, y) - meang_e) ^ 2)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
sumb1 = sumb1 + ((Blu(x, y) - meanb_o) * (nBlu(x, y) - meanb_e))
sumb2 = sumb2 + ((Blu(x, y) - meanb_o) ^ 2)
sumb3 = sumb3 + ((nBlu(x, y) - meanb_e) ^ 2)

Next x: Next y
sumr1 = sumr1 / N
sumr2 = sumr2 / N
sumr3 = sumr3 / N

sumg1 = sumg1 / N
sumg2 = sumg2 / N
sumg3 = sumg3 / N

sumb1 = sumb1 / N
sumb2 = sumb2 / N
sumb3 = sumb3 / N

Corr_r = sumr1 / Sqr(sumr2 * sumr3)
Corr_g = sumg1 / Sqr(sumg2 * sumg3)
Corr_b = sumb1 / Sqr(sumb2 * sumb3)
Corr = (Corr_r + Corr_g + Corr_b) / 3
Label1.Caption = Corr
```

Comment: Are your input correct? Maybe Red, nred are 0-255 but the formula expect 0-1

Comment: What value do you for the correlation coefficient for two red images ? (R=255,G=0,B=0)

Comment: Could you trim the code down to just red (assuming it's giving bad values)?  And I would suggest better names than `sum[rgb][123]`: `sum[rgb]1` could be `covar[rgb]`, `sum[rgb]2` could be `var[rgb]`, and `sum[rgb]3` could be `nvar[rgb]`.

Comment: After trimming the code to just red, can you run your algorithm on a image of 2 by 2 pixels with only one of the red pixels set to 4 and the rest to 0. It should give an average of 1 and the equation will be 3/sqrt(3*3).

Comment: @the_lotus The input is correct all the color values. I check it during the debug.

Comment: @Teepeemm The correlation coefficient for red shroud be between 1-0 and the same for Green and Blue.

Comment: @Jaco The result did not changed. The correlation coefficient must be lower than one between any two different images.

Comment: @user3819984 I understand that.  I'm saying that I don't see anything wrong with your code, and suspect the error may be elsewhere.  You'll need to turn this into a [mcve], of which one step is to only focus on red.  And include `Sqr`.  And include the data for `Red` and `nred` (probably just by literally typing it in).

Comment: What image resolution are you using? if it is too big then may be you are overflowing your data types ... try smaller ones first and if not wrong try to switch to bigger variables or make sure you are on floats in range `<0,1>`...

Comment: I agree with @Spektre, it is very likely you are overflowing your data types.   There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code that you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

I have limited your code snippet to red and have created two functions that just return one pixel value for `x=0` and `y=0`. This code snippet seems to be working and returns correlation coefficients between -1 and 1. Please note that I have declared `meanr_o`, `meanr_e`, `sumr1`, `sumr2`, `sumr3`, `Corr_r` as doubles. I am also using `Math.Sqrt` instead of `Sqr`, you can find a .NET fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0N2LOb).

```
Public Module Module1
    Function Red(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer
        ' local variable declaration */
        Dim result As Integer
        If (x = 0) And (y = 0) Then
            result = 255
        Else
            result = 0
        End If
        Red = result
    End Function

    Function nred(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer
        ' local variable declaration */
        Dim result As Integer
        If (x = 0) And (y = 0) Then
            result = 255
        Else
            result = 0
        End If
        nred = result
    End Function

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim hgt, wid, N As Integer
        Dim meanr_o, meanr_e, sumr1, sumr2, sumr3, Corr_r As Double
        hgt = 255
        wid = 255
        For y = 0 To hgt - 1 : For x = 0 To wid - 1
                meanr_o = meanr_o + Red(x, y)
                meanr_e = meanr_e + nred(x, y)
                N = N + 1
            Next x : Next y

        meanr_o = meanr_o / N
        meanr_e = meanr_e / N

        For y = 0 To hgt - 1 : For x = 0 To wid - 1
                sumr1 = sumr1 + ((Red(x, y) - meanr_o) * (nred(x, y) - meanr_e))
                sumr2 = sumr2 + ((Red(x, y) - meanr_o) ^ 2)
                sumr3 = sumr3 + ((nred(x, y) - meanr_e) ^ 2)
            Next x : Next y
        sumr1 = sumr1 / N
        sumr2 = sumr2 / N
        sumr3 = sumr3 / N

        Corr_r = sumr1 / System.Math.Sqrt(sumr2 * sumr3)
        System.Console.WriteLine("Correlation is : {0}", Corr_r)

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, the code returns correlation coefficient values incorrectly such as -6 or -4. I checked all the red() and nred() values but it not working.

Comment: The example as is return a correlation coefficient of 1 and the output is "Correlation is : 1" using .NET Framework 4.5. What does the example return for you?

Comment: The example returns 1, however when use it for images the results are not correct.

Comment: Can you post any of these images ? I wonder if there is a bug in the code returning the pixel values from your images.